# Flash in Addon Builder Panel

Tags: flash, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Having a simple YouTube flash element in panel gives a buggy experience. I use below code.

```
var Widget = require("widget").Widget;

exports.main = function() {

var data = require("self").data;

var yt_panel = require("panel").Panel({
  width: 500,
  height: 500,
  contentURL: "http://www.youtube.com/embed/vSNapvrROo4"
});

require("sdk/widget").Widget({
  label: "YT",
  id: "yt-panel",
  contentURL: "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/web-2/16/Youtube-icon.png",
  panel: yt_panel
});
};
```

Is the code I use is wrong to place flash in panels or does Add-on SDK have some defects?

Comment: I ran your code, it doesn't work for me either, unsure why.

Comment: Yes code is clear. I tried many web pages which contain Flash items in them and they were all buggy. Can you file a bug for Add-on SDK?

Comment: How about you [file a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Add-on%20SDK&component=General) yourself?

Comment: I can not even post to Jetpack Google forums. [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mozilla-labs-jetpack) Normally they do not fix the bugs users sent. If canuckistani files the bug it is sure it will get fixed.

Comment: Actually I would really prefer you file the bug.

Comment: I sent the bug thanks  [link](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=952578) Please have a look at this. I have many add-ons to write which are waiting because of this bug.

Comment: I am waiting for the bug confirmation but nobody from Firefox cares!